# Register Caffeine Cache in Spring Actuator (CacheManager)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cache, caffeine

We're using Spring Boot 2 and Spring Actuator. When creating a cache like the following:

```java
@Bean
public CaffeineCache someCache() {
    return new CaffeineCache("my-cache",
            Caffeine.newBuilder()
                    .maximumSize(1000)
                    .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build());
}
```

it is registered into Spring Actuator and can be accessed and handle via endpoints:

```
❯ http GET localhost:8080/actuator/caches

{
    "cacheManagers": {
        "cacheManager": {
            "caches": {
                "my-cache": {
                    "target": "com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalManualCache"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is valid when using the annotation `@Cacheable` - but I would like to create a cache and use it as a map.

Therefore, I can create:

```java
    @Bean
    public com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Cache<String, MyObject> customCache(QueryServiceProperties config) {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(10)
                .expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
    }
```

And it works but it cannot be discovered by *Spring Actuator*. Is there any way to register this kind of cache?

Answer (score 3):

Addapted from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49730678) I did the following:

```
@Autowired
private CacheMetricsRegistrar cacheMetricsRegistrar;
private LoadingCache<Key, MyObject> cache;


@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(10_000)
            .refreshAfterWrite(cacheDuration)
            .recordStats()
            .build(this::loadMyObject);

    // trick the compiler
    Cache tmp = cache;
    cacheMetricsRegistrar.bindCacheToRegistry(new CaffeineCache(CACHE_NAME, tmp), Tag.of("name", CACHE_NAME));
}
```

The Cache should now show up in the cache actuator endpoints, e.g. "http://localhost:8080/metrics/cache.gets"

Comment: What is that supposed `trick the compiler` step doing?

Answer (score 0):

use `CacheManager`

add your custom cache into `CacheManager`, inject `CacheManager` and get that cache out for your usage.
see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html for some further details