# Unable to get stats for Caffeine cache (Spring 5)

Tags: java, spring, caching

I got stuck on a (hopefully) very simple problem. I added a Caffeine cache to my Spring application and this cache works well.
Now I tried to get the statistics for this cache, but I can't find a way to get to the right methods...

```
import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        CaffeineCacheManager cacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager("bin");
        cacheManager.setCaffeine(Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(10000)
                .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .recordStats());
        return cacheManager;
    }

}
```

How can I get stats for this cache?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158365/register-caffeine-cache-in-spring-actuator-cachemanager). You can register it with Spring's metrics reporting infrastructure.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint.
Unfortunately, this seems to work only for Spring Boot > 2.
I am using Spring 5 (not Boot) in my application.
Anyway, there should be way there, too.

Comment: Oh, I guess [application metrics](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector) is a Boot concept. There is native support in [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/docs/ref/cache), [Dropwizard Metrics](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/tree/release/4.1.x/metrics-caffeine), and [Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#caches).

Answer (score 0):

Inject CacheManager and then just get it.

```
CacheStats stats = ((CaffeineCache) cacheManager.getCache("bin")).getNativeCache().stats();
```

Works for me.

Comment: I had problem to retrieve the stats too. this worked for me !! Thanks